# Connecting to Access database through HTML on PC

Tags: html, database, ms-access

So I'm trying to figure out how to connect to an access database that is on my  desktop through html. Everything I've found so far involves the DB being server side and people mentioning ASP.net or just using SQL or mySQL instead. I just need to know how to get the connection up and running. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of web programming language. That can be PHP or ASP.NET or Java or whatever, but you need *something* else -- HTML can't connect to a database on its own.

I'd highly advise that you take this opportunity to switch to another database server (like SQL Server or MySQL, like you mentioned). Microsoft Access is not well suited to use in web applications.

Comment: I understand that I would need to use something like PHP. How would I implement that then?

Answer (score 0):

You're just going to get the same answers here. If you want to stay with Access, ASP.Net is the way to go. Access isn't webbased, most other databases are, so it's a bad fit.

If you want a professional solution, you could get yourself a Sharepoint server and put an Access WebApp on there. But note that this is intended for larger businesses, and priced accordingly, and your database will be limited in features (no VBA for example).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read or modify files from your (or anyone else) computer with frontend/html/javascript. Yes, you need some backend to connect to your database on your computer/server.

There are databases that work on client side/frontend, like [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), but it's not ms access and I don't think it's what you want.